# JS: Join Array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i use Array.Join on every sub-member of array and on array itself for, let's say, separate elements of Parent array with **";"** and every element of child arrays with **"$"**.

```
let arr = [[1, 2,], [3, 4], [5,6]];
console.log(arr.join(";")); //Output is 1,2;3,4;5,6

//Pseudocode for expected output
console.log(
  foreach (subArr in arr) {
    subArr.join("$");
  }
  arr.join(";")); //Expected output 1$2;3$4;5$6
```

Comment: Plenty of ways to do it. map, join, reduce, for loop, etc. Your pseudo code has the right idea, it just needs to somehow store it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could join the inner arrays and then the outer array for the given nested data structure.

The [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
a => a.join('$')
```

is (nearly, see link above) the same as

```
function (a) { return a.join('$'); }
```

which uses [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), where each element of an array is joined with a separator `'$'` and returned.

And this function is the callback for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). For every element of the outer array, it calles the function and returns a string with `'1$2'`.

The result is an array of strings like

```
[
    '1$2',
    '3$4',
    '5$6'
]
```

This array is also joined and the result is now a string with the parts joined by `';'`.

```
'1$2;3$4;5$6'
```

```js
let array = [[1, 2,], [3, 4], [5,6]],
    string = array.map(a => a.join('$')).join(';');
    
console.log(string);
```

ES5 version:

```js
let array2 = [[1, 2,], [3, 4], [5,6]],
    string2 = array2.map(function(a){ return a.join('$') }).join(';');
    
console.log(string2);
```

Arrow functions don't need return statement, it would be like: `["1$2","2$3","3$4"].join(";")`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i wanted! Could you please explain this part **array.map(a => a.join('$')).join(';');**? I tried to rewrite it on plain JS but got confused with the usage of a => ... Is it arrow function and how does join().join() even works?

Comment: Basically map() produce an array and second join() runs on newly created array.

Comment: @serkan and @nina thanks again, that was really helpful. I tried to break your examples down even more just for understanding how it works and finally got it to work:

`let array = [[1, 2,], [3, 4], [5,6]];
let array2 = [];

let iterArr = function () {
 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array2.push(array[i].join('$'));
 }
};

iterArr();

console.log(array2.join(';'));`